# Check IEnumerable Count

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Let's say I have a collection of expensive-to-generate objects stored in an IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Expensive> expensiveObjects = CreateExpensiveIEnumerable();
```

Now I will iterate over everything in `expensiveObjects` and afterwards, I want to know if it was empty.

Here is how I am doing that currently.

```
var count = 0;
foreach(var e in expensiveObjects)
{
    count++;
    //other processing
}
if (count == 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

This works fine, but I'm asking here as a fishing expedition to figure out if there are any clever ways to implement this functionality without either:

- iterating over at least part of the collection twice by using the `Any()` method
- Performing a `ToList()` up-front on my collection

Any other suggestions or should I just stick with a simple counting variable?

Comment: I'm confused, you say the objects are “stored” in the `IEnumerable` but you also don't want to iterate it twice, which looks like the objects are generated each time. So which one is it? Could you describe the characteristics on the `IEnumerable` in more detail?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, let's say CreateExpensiveIEnumerable() generates its return values through a `yield return` statement, does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your approach is reasonable if you don't want (or can't) have the whole collection in memory. One minor change: if you don't need the count, just whether the collection was empty or not, use a simple `bool`:

```
bool any = false;

foreach(var e in expensiveObjects)
{
    any = true;

    //other processing
}

if (any)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One alternative would be to enclose this logic into an extension method:

```
static bool ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    bool any = false;

    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        any = true;

        action(x);
    }

    return any;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool any = expensiveObjects.ForEach(e => /* other processing */);

if (any)
{
    //do something
}
```

But I think that in this specific case, this doesn't make much sense and using normal `foreach` with additional variable is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type that's implementing your `IEnumerable`. Per [this Jon Skeet SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738329/how-does-tolist-on-an-ienumerable-work), calling `.ToList()` doesn't automatically mean an enumeration.

I'd make sure `expensiveObjects` is some `IList`, and if that's the case I'd call `.ToList()` up-front, using the `Count` property instead of incrementing a `count` variable during the enumeration.

```
var items = expensiveObjects as IList<Expensive> ?? expensiveObjects.ToList();
```

Now if `expensiveObjects` is some "pure" `IEnumerable`, I believe this would effectively iterate the items, so it *could* be more efficient to increment a `count` variable as you're iterating.

The best way to find out, ...is to try & profile both ways :)

Comment: In my example, this is a "pure" `IEnumerable`, so based on your answer, I'd be best off with my current approach.

Comment: I would *think* so, but profiling/timing both alternatives (or being more knowledgeable about these subtleties than I am :s) would be the best way to find out for sure.

Comment: @ledbutter Why not generate them into a `List<T>`?

Comment: because then they would all be in memory at once, and I'd rather not do that